# jquery document function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have such html piece of code:

```
<ul class="myClass">
    <li><a href="url1.html">first link</a></li>
    <li><a href="url2.html">second link</a></li>
    <li><a href="url2.html">third link</a></li>
    <li><a href="url3.html">fourth link</a></li>
</ul>
```

The idea is that when I press the link, it should write to the pressed link next property string: class="active". For instance, if we have

```
<li><a href="url1.html">first link</a></li>`
```

and I press it, the jQuery function should change it to:

```
<li><a class="active" href="url1.html">first link</a></li>
```

But my jQuery function doesn't really work. I'll very grateful if you can help me.
Here is source of jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var currentUrl = document.location.pathname;
   $('#myClass').each(function() {
       if ( currentUrl == $(this).children('a').attr('href')) {
           $(this).children('a').addClass('active');
       }
   });
});
```

UPDATE
I put log `console.log(currentUrl +"=="+ $(this).children('a').attr('href'));`
and it said that the state is undefined. I think the "if" condition is not executed, because, I put and else condition and put and `alert` there, so any pressing calls alert and `if` condition is never executed.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "doesn't really work" - what is happening that shouldn't?

Comment: Have you looked at what this returns: `console.log(currentUrl +"=="+ $(this).children('a').attr('href'));`

Comment: @AnthonyGrist when i press the link, the 'class="active"' property is not installed

Comment: You should edit your question to be more clear.  You're asking to add a class to a link when pressed, but your function example seems to imply you want a class to be added to a link according to what url you're currently at, two completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve, could be shortly written like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
     var curl = document.location.pathname;  //current url
     curl = curl.substr( curl.lastIndexOf('/')+1 );
     $('.myClass a[href="'+curl+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: @JohnSmith Probably, it is because, there is no such `a` element, which `href` attribute is equal to `document.location.pathname`. Maybe there are additional characters in `document.location.pathname`, which must be removed, before passing to `jquery selector`

Comment: @ Engineer I alerted `document.location.pathname` and it alerted me my  urls, which I clicked.

Comment: @ Engineer now i understand what you mean. i have `/projectName/clickedUrl.html`. so how can i remove `/projectName/` part? may be it'll help...

Comment: @ Engineer thnx a lot! it really helped!

Answer (score 2):

`#myClass` is an **id** selector, not a class selector. You want `.myClass`

`children()` will only select the children (the `li` elements), which don't have `href` attributes and won't match `a`.

You want `#myClass` to be `.myClass > li` so you loop over the list items.

Comment: I'm not really good at jquery, so i don't really reailize how it should be

Comment: @John: That's what documentation is for: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ;)

Answer (score -1):

Use the [jQuery click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.myClass a').click(function() {
         $(this).addClass('active');
     });
});
```

This answer addresses your question:

"The idea is that when I press the link, it should write to the pressed link next property string: class="active". For instance, if we have

```
<li><a href="url1.html">first link</a></li>`
```

and I press it, the jquery function should change it to:

```
<li><a class="active" href="url1.html">first link</a></li>
```

"

I guess you had a different issue, but it wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: @JohnSmith Fixed missing parenthesis